# Select two rows where the sum of two rows is equal to a value

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table as follows:

```
| id | value |
--------------
| 1  | 6     |
| 2  | 8     |
| 3  | 5     |
| 4  | 12    |
| 5  | 6     |
```

I want to return the two rows for which added together will equal a certain value

e.g. I want to get 2 rows where the total is 18, so in the above table it should return:

```
| id | value |
--------------
| 1  | 6    |
| 4  | 12   |
```

...as the sum of values here is 18. It shouldn't match on the other 3 rows even if they add up to the total as it can only be sum of 2 rows in this case.

Also, if there are multiple pairs that add up to the required value, it should only return the first match.

edit:

Came up with this which seems to do the trick but I'm not sure it's the best method

```
SELECT *, (t1.value+t2.value) AS total
FROM test t1, test t2
WHERE t1.id != t2.id
HAVING total = 18
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How is this the "first" match? wouldn't ids 1 and 4 be the first match (6+12=18)?

Comment: Yeah, didn't properly think through my sample table. Have edited to prevent confusion!

Comment: This is an np-complete problem, so you have to try every combination, filter out those that match, then arrange them in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something similar to what you're after...

```
SELECT x.id x_id
     , y.id y_id
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y   
    ON y.id > x.id 
  WHERE x.value + y.value = 18 
  ORDER 
     BY x.id
      , y.id
  LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't really lend to such queries. The only [admitedly god aweful] solution I can think of is to self-join the table to get the two records, and then put this join in a CTE and use `union all` to get the two records on separate rows:

```
WITH summer AS (
    SELECT   a.id AS a_id, a.value AS a_value, b.id AS b_id, b.value AS b_value
    FROM     mytable a
    JOIN     mytable b ON a.id <> b.id AND a.value + b.value = 18
    ORDER BY a.id, b.id
    LIMIT    1
)
SELECT a_id, a_value
FROM   summer
UNION ALL
SELECT b_id, b_value
FROM   summer
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple query for doing it:

```
SELECT 
    number1.id, number2.id
FROM
    number AS number1
        JOIN
    number AS number2 ON number1.value + number2.value = 18
        AND number2.id > number1.id
```